# Can't track open push from parse

Tags: android, parse-platform

I have implemented parse notification, but open push analytic seems not working. 
The flow is when i receive a push notification i will invoke myCustomReceiver, and when i open the push it will be invoke MainActivity to process the data from notification. 
So my code in MainActivity to process data is:

```
 private void openChannelFromNotification() {
    //check if coming from noti it will have channelId
    String channelId = getIntent().getStringExtra(EXTRA_CHANNEL_ID);
    if (channelId != null) {
        Intent channelIntent = new Intent(this, ViewerActivity.class);
        channelIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        channelIntent.putExtra(ViewerActivity.EXTRA_CHANNEL_ID, channelId);
        this.startActivity(channelIntent);


        Log.d(MainActivity.this.getClass().getSimpleName(), "Open Push Notification " + getIntent());

        ParseAnalytics.trackAppOpenedInBackground(getIntent());
    }
}
```

I thing the ParseAnalytics.trackAppOpenedInBackground(getIntent()); not track the push open analytic.

is anybody get same issue and find solution ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I checked by changing the function from trackAppOpenedInBackground -> trackEventInBackground.Sometimes it works but sometimes it doesn't.No idea whether it is server side delay or any code missing.I checked the debug points also the function is calling.